# R visualize the behaviour of customers

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have data about which store has been visited by thousands of customers and by year  :

```
data <- "Customer_ID Year Store_Visited 
1          1        2010         A         
2          1        2011         A_B         
3          1        2012         A_B         
4          2        2010         A        
5          2        2012         B  
6          3        2010         A
7          3        2011         A
8          3        2011         A
 "
data <- read.table(text=data, header = TRUE)
```

What I'd like to visualize is the impact of the opening of the store B, on the frequentation of the store A.

### Here is a proposal :

1. 3 customers went to the store A in 2010 : there is a line with a thickness=3 in 2010
2. In 2011 the store B opened. 1 customer came only in the store A, 1 came in both stores, and the third one didn't came in our store : a line with a thickness=1 goes from A to A_and_B, and a line with a thickness=1 goes from A to A.
3. In 2012, 1 customer who went in stores A_and_B in the previous year still went to stores A_and_B : line with a thickness=1 goes from A_and_B to A_and_B. 1 customer who went in store A in the previous year still went to store A :
   line with a thickness=1 goes from A to A, 1 customer  went to store B and didn't visit our stores in the previous year : line with a thickness=1 from B to B.

[image: http://imgur.com/U9UG4Hp]

**What do you think of this way to visualize the behaviour of these customers ?**

**How can I do it in R (with ggplot for instance) ?**

For information I have thousands of customers, so I will maybe have to aggregate user who did the same visits in two consecutive years!

Comment: Sounds like you want a Sankey chart.  I haven't had a chance to look around to see if there is an R only implementation.  I did find **[this](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/example_build_network_sankey.html)**, but it looks like it's not R only.

Comment: You may be able to use [the ggplot2 example code for Minard's classic troop movement graph](http://euclid.psych.yorku.ca/SCS/Gallery/re-minard.html) to design something similar. It's a pretty simple use of `geom_path`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. Firstly, I think your code needs a minor change on line 8 - Year should be 2012 I think. Thus:

```
data <- "Customer_ID Year Store_Visited 
1          1        2010         A         
2          1        2011         A_B         
3          1        2012         A_B         
4          2        2010         A        
5          2        2012         B  
6          3        2010         A
7          3        2011         A
8          3        2012         A
 "
data <- read.table(text=data, header = TRUE)
```

It's relatively easy to plot the diagram you're after from this using "lines":

### Step 1: Arrange the data for plotting

This involves working out the number of people going from one place to another each year
A) The possible moves are:

```
Stores = unique(data$Store_Visited)
#Get the range of possible moves
possibleMoves = character()
for(i in seq(1,length(Stores))){
    for(j in seq(1, length(Stores))){
        possibleMoves = c(possibleMoves, paste(Stores[i], Stores[j], sep="-"))
    }
}
```

B) The moves for the first year are:

```
Years = unique(data$Year)
MoveMat = data.frame(Years)
for(i in seq(1,length(possibleMoves))){MoveMat[possibleMoves[i]]=0}
FirstYear = table(data$Year, data$Store)[1,]
MoveMat[1,which(names(MoveMat) %in% paste(names(FirstYear), names(FirstYear), sep="-"))] = FirstYear
```

C) The moves for every other year are:

```
for(i in seq(2, length(Years))){
    temp = merge(subset(data, Year==Years[i-1]), subset(data, Year==Years[i]), by="Customer_ID", all.y=T)
    temp_new = which(is.na(temp[,3])); temp[temp_new,3] = temp[temp_new,5]  
    temp = table(paste(temp[,3], temp[,5],sep="-"))
    MoveMat[i,which(names(MoveMat) %in% names(temp))] = temp    
}
```

Now we have the moves by year in "MoveMat"

### Step 2: Plot the moves

Given the new format, it's relatively simple to plot this with "lines":
A) Set up the plotting window

```
plot(c(1,length(Years)+1), c(1,length(Stores)), col=0)
```

B) And cycle through plotting each year:

```
for(y in seq(1,length(Years))){
    count = 0
    for(i in seq(1,length(Stores))){
        for(j in seq(1,length(Stores))){
            count = count+1
            if(MoveMat[y,count+1]>0){
                lines(c(y,y+1), c(i,j), lwd=MoveMat[y,count+1])
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

That produces a figure similar to the one you have sketched. Is that what you're after? 
[image]

The whole code is below to make it easy for you to copy and paste:

```
data <- "Customer_ID Year Store_Visited 
1          1        2010         A         
2          1        2011         A_B         
3          1        2012         A_B         
4          2        2010         A        
5          2        2012         B  
6          3        2010         A
7          3        2011         A
8          3        2012         A
 "
data <- read.table(text=data, header = TRUE)

#Arrange data to give width of steps each year
Stores = unique(data$Store_Visited)
#Get the range of possible moves
possibleMoves = character()
for(i in seq(1,length(Stores))){
    for(j in seq(1, length(Stores))){
        possibleMoves = c(possibleMoves, paste(Stores[i], Stores[j], sep="-"))
    }
}
#First year is just the first column of the year-store table
Years = unique(data$Year)
MoveMat = data.frame(Years)
for(i in seq(1,length(possibleMoves))){MoveMat[possibleMoves[i]]=0}
FirstYear = table(data$Year, data$Store)[1,]
MoveMat[1,which(names(MoveMat) %in% paste(names(FirstYear), names(FirstYear), sep="-"))] = FirstYear
#Now the other years
for(i in seq(2, length(Years))){
    temp = merge(subset(data, Year==Years[i-1]), subset(data, Year==Years[i]), by="Customer_ID", all.y=T)
    temp_new = which(is.na(temp[,3])); temp[temp_new,3] = temp[temp_new,5]  
    temp = table(paste(temp[,3], temp[,5],sep="-"))
    MoveMat[i,which(names(MoveMat) %in% names(temp))] = temp    
}

#Now plot the results
#Set up plot
plot(c(1,length(Years)+1), c(1,length(Stores)), col=0)
#Plot each year
for(y in seq(1,length(Years))){
    count = 0
    for(i in seq(1,length(Stores))){
        for(j in seq(1,length(Stores))){
            count = count+1
            if(MoveMat[y,count+1]>0){
                lines(c(y,y+1), c(i,j), lwd=MoveMat[y,count+1]*3)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```